# Como hago un array que aumente su tamaño a medida que introduzco mas numeros?

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un codigo para meter notas de alumnos dentro de un array, y luego ir sacando por pantalla el numero del alumno junto con la nota que se ha introducido de ese alumno, pero se me complica a la hora de hacer el array, ya que no se como hacerlo para que al utilizar una funcion que es añadir mas notas el array aumente su tamaño.

```
 int nueva_nota; 
    float nota;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int []alumno;
    

    for (int i=0; i<alumno; i++){
    System.out.println("La nota del alumno"+i+"es:");
    nota = entrada.nextFloat();
    
    do{
        System.out.println("Quieres introducir una nota? 1 Si, 2 No");
        nueva_nota = entrada.nextInt();
        if (nueva_nota < 1 || nueva_nota > 2){
            System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
        }
        
    }while (nueva_nota < 1 || nueva_nota > 2);
}while (nueva_nota == 1);
```

Sé que esta bastante mal redactado, porque estoy empezando con los arrays, pero espero que se entienda a lo que me quiero referir.

Comment: un array tiene tamaño estático es decir si lo declaras para 5 elementos solo podrá tener 5 elementos no mas,quizá sea mejor idea un ArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tamaño de un array en Java es estático, una vez creado no se puede modificar. La única solución es crear un nuevo array y copiar todos los elementos al nuevo array.

De hecho, es lo que internamente hace ArrayList: Crea un array de un tamaño inicial (por defecto 10) y, cuando necesita más espacio, crea un nuevo array más grande.